# Retrieve JSON Object from REST Blogger Api Request with PHP

Tags: php, rest, blogger

I'm still wondering how to get json object from REST Api request from this link https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using.

It says `GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953?key=YOUR-API-KEY` request will give informations about particular blog.

I'm also PHP noobs. Here's my code.

```
<?php
$blogID = 'xxx'; 
$apikey = 'yyy';

$requestURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{$blogID}?key={$apikey}";

$json = file_get_contents($requestURL);
print_r($json);

?>
```

I have no idea about this, so please help me to find where the problem is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestURL));
```

You are fetching a `JSON` string and trying to `print_r` it, which only works on arrays.

`json_decode`, as its name implies, decodes the JSON string and transforms it into an array / object.